# IIS Express 8 vs. IIS

Tags: windows, visual-studio, iis, iis-express

I downloaded Visual Studio 2013 Express. I have IIS Express 8 Installed.

Is it OK if I download IIS 7 or 8? Do I have to do anything to make Visual Studio 2013 work with IIS 7 or 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't download IIS7 or 8 since they are part of the Windows operating system. You have to enable them in **Windows Features**.

Visual Studio can work out-of-the-box with IIS proper. You just have to configure your site to use it. In your project properties for your web site, select **Web** and edit the **Servers** section.